# Reference Other Model from Generic View

Tags: django, django-views

I'm having a very difficult time finding an answer for this.  Maybe its possible, maybe it isn't.  If I have a reference from another model, lets say model1.customer_id = 123, how can I use that reference in a listview to display model2.company_name where the primary key (also named customer_id) of the model1 model is also == 123?

Both models contain their own respective primary keys.

```
class TblCompanies(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(db_column='Company Name', max_length=50)
    billing_address = models.CharField(db_column='Billing Address', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    company_id = models.AutoField(db_column='Company ID', primary_key=True)
    notes = models.TextField(db_column='Notes', blank=True, null=True)

class TblServiceRecords(models.Model):
    sr_id = models.CharField(db_column='SR ID', primary_key=True, max_length=50)  
    company_id = models.ForeignKey('TblCompanies', on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    date_entered = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Date Entered', blank=True, null=True)  
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Date Updated', blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show your models. `customer_id` is presumably a ForeignKey:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    ...
    customer = models.ForeignKey('model2')
```

so in your template you can just do:

```
{{ model_1_instance.customer.company_name }}
```

Comment: No foreign keys here due to the constraints of this conversion.

Comment: That doesn't follow at all. What you describe **is exactly** a foreign key. You just need to declare it as such in your models.py.

Comment: If I remember right, when I tried that, Django got pissed off because the model2 also had a primary key.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments; update your question with this.

Comment: There's nothing here that would prevent you declaring `customer` as a foreign key. Although I don't understand what it's pointing to, since neither model is called Customer and both have PKs that are charfields.

Comment: Django didn't get pissed at me this time.  I just switched it to a foreignkey and don't have any errors.  Wonder what I boogered up last time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this will work:

```
class Model1(models.Model):    
    customer_id = = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey('model2',db_column='customer',related_name='customer')
class Model2(models.Model):    
    customer_id1 = = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    model1_instance = Model1.objects.get(customer_id=123)
     in template use following code
    {{ model1_instance.customer.company_name }}
```

Comment: 'model1_instance = Model1.objects.get(customer_id=123)'. What I'm describing would be model1.customer_id is defined by model2.customer_id.  Your code doesn't look to do this but instead expects input?  Maybe I'm wrong.   I'll test at work this morning.  How do you pass the input of model2.customer_id to model1_instance?

Comment: Hi, through the foreign key **customer**, you will get model2.customer_id1 and model2.company_name  by **Model1**  instance

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give it a try today!